# How do I change the name of an object I'm instantiating within a loop, with a different name on each iteration, as shown below?

Tags: python, object

```
if len(args_list) > 1:
        i = 0
        for arg in args_list:
            arg = TestObject(arg)
            i = i + 1
```

My goal is to create a single object per arg (which I will pass into another function to parse) in args_list. TestObject is an object class I created and imported. I was hoping to name the object by "arg" each time allowing for obvious naming convention, although this throws an error, as seen in the attached image.

[Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhHfK.png)

I have tried leveraging a counter such as i, although I'm, not sure how to concatenate an int variable to an object name.

Example: `ObjectX+i = newObject`. This is obviously incorrect, but the idea I was after.